# fill div with html file via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I have a div on my main html file;

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

and two html files: login.html & singup.html.

Also a navigation bar is present on the top of my page.
Is it possible to fill the content of the div with the use of AJAX with the content of the login file when the login button is clicked and fill it with singup.html when the register button is clicked?

these are the buttons:

```
<li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the `responeText` of the request and set the `div.innerHTML = AJAX.responseText;`.

If your `login.html` page built as a stand-alone page, I mean, contains `<html><head></head><body>...</body></html>` tags - you might want to add just the inner content of the `<body>` tag. You can use regexp to get it:

```
div.innerHTML = AJAX.responseText.replace( /<body>([\s\S]*)<\/body>/i , "$1" );
```

Comment: it does contain the head and body tags. Will the extracted content of login.html use the css used in main.html? And how do I have to use my buttons exactly ?

Comment: If it is in the attributes of the loaded page. Now I see... You cannot load a full HTML page into a `<div>`. You may try, but the result will be browser depended...

Comment: so its better to save the contents of login.html in a plain txt file, and then load it. But what link should I use in the <a href="?">

Comment: Dont use a link. Use a function to call the proper AJAX request by click.

Comment: I now gave the button a class="register" and a js file that will replace the content of the div. It does not work yet.