# JQuery mobile Ajax request doens't update div

Tags: html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a div called **Tickets** and 2 buttons 'open' and 'dicht'
if i press open or dicht a function called **getTickets(status)** is called with the status open or dicht.

there is nothing wrong with the request because data returns all the content i want. the probleem is that the div tickets doesn't get the data content

is there something wrong with **$('tickets').html(data);** ?

Here is mij code:

getTickets(status)

```
function getTickets(status) {


        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/getTickets.php',
            data: {"status": status},
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                if(status == "open"){
                    $('#open').addClass('active');
                    $('#closed').removeClass('active');
                }
                if(status == "dicht"){ 
                    $('#closed').addClass('active');
                     $('#open').removeClass('active');
                }
                $('#tickets').html(data);
            }
        });


    }
```

the 2 buttons with the div tickets

```
<div data-role="page" id="ticketsPage" rel="Ticketoverzicht" >
        <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs"><div data-role="navbar"><ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline active" id="open" onclick="getTickets('open');">Open</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" id="closed" onclick="getTickets('dicht');">Dicht</a></li></ul></div>
        </div>
    <div id="tickets"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338829/fill-div-with-html-file-via-ajax

Comment: Try console to check error as there is nothing wrong with code

Comment: Nop that doesnt help xD @Tosfera

Comment: I got zero errors @parveen :)

Comment: Err question, a button refreshes the page. If you fill in data in the div and your page refreshes, your data is lost. Try to add; return false; after the getTickets('dicht'); in the onclick, to see if it works then.

Comment: use  <a href="javascript:;" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline active" id="open" onclick="getTickets('open');">

Comment: @Tosfera no this is not the case because this code is used in an iframe.

Comment: @parveen thx alot this works! Can you explain though? and put this as an answer so i can upvote it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<a href="javascript:;" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline active" id="open" onclick="getTickets('open');">`  and do check console for error .